# Vuetify Font awesome SVG integration problem

Tags: vue.js, svg, icons, vuetify.js, font-awesome

I am trying to get  component from vuetify working. I am using fontawesome svg icons and i followed the docs regarding installation page. Here is how i got it registered:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { fas, faBell } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

Vue.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon); // Register component globally
library.add(fas, faBell); // Include needed icons

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "faSvg",
  },
});
```

However when I am using code such as this :

```
 <v-icon>fas fa-bell</v-icon>
```

for displaying icons it does not work. I got it working by using the font-awesome-icon component but i would like to use the native vuetify v-icon component.

Do you guys have any idea what might be the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if only adding faBell to library changes things? That would be the actual icon.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the link in your `<head>`.
If you read the [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#font-awesome-5-icons) you'll see:

> The easiest way to get started with FontAwesome is to use a cdn. Within the head of your main index.html place this snippet:
> `<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Even if it doesn't specify the same for the SVG version, I only got it to work by adding that link to my `<head>`.